# How do you use functions inside a Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

While modeling a falling object, the following code works fine:

```
h[t_] = 10 - g*t^2/2;

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Blue, Sphere[{0, 0, h[t]}, 2]} {t, 0, 6}]
```

But if I try to define a center like:

```
h[t_] = 10 - g*t^2/2;
center = {0, 0, h[t]}
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Blue, Sphere[center, 2]} {t, 0, 6}]
```

It throws the error:

```
Coordinate {0, 0, 10 - 4.905 $CellContext`t^2} should be a triple of numbers, or a Scaled form.
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the syntax errors and added definition. This works

```
g = 9.81;
h[t_] := 10 - g*t^2/2;
center[t_] := {0, 0, h[t]};
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Blue, Sphere[center[t], 2]}, Axes -> True], {t, 0, 6},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t}
 ]
```

Now `center` is used since it depends on `t` and Manipulate tracks `t`

Comment: It's also a good idea to add the setting `SaveDefinitions -> True` in situations like this.

Comment: @J.M. yes, But myself, I do not write things like the above. I would put all functions needed by Manipulate in its Initialization section.

Comment: Yes, I agree that's even better practice.

Comment: It's clear now. What do you mean by "put all functions needed by Manipulate in its Initialization section".

Comment: @Chegon  it is like this  [Initialization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Initialization.html) where functions used by Manipulate are put inside Manipulate initialization section.